# Responsive en datatables

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, datatables

hoy mi pregunta tiene que ver con el **Responsive** en mis **DataTables**.
El programa en el cual trabajo actualmente tiene bastantes **DataTables** que no tienen **Responsive**, deberia funcionar para equipos de pantalla mediana, tablets y celulares, pero se dañan al reducir el ancho de la página, quisiera saber como puede ser mas conveniente repararlas, sea por **css, js,** o **php**

Así se ve de un tamaño *Normal* o una resolución de mas de **1350 pixeles**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve del tamaño de un tablet o una resolución de almenos **800 pixeles**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve del tamaño de un celular o un resulución menor o igual a **414 pixeles**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al reducir el tamaño de la página, el borde va escondiendo los campos de la tabla, deberian permanecer dentro de las margenes de la pagina. ¿Habrá algún estilo o etiqueta que me pueda ayudar?

En estos momentos cuando declaro la tabla en el html tengo las siguientes etiquetas

```html
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tabla Ejemplo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td>
            <th>Ejamplo1</th>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Para tablas, la solución por la que se suele optar es la de tener un contenedor que la envuelva y al que se le pueda hacer scroll horizontal.

**Fuente:** [Ejemplo ya hecho](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.asp)

Comment: lo ensayaré y te aviso, Gracias

Comment: el overflow-X me ayudó bastante, lo usé masivamente en mis dataTables, Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo normal en estos casos es meter un media Query en css:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .cuadrado {
    width:150px;
  }
}
```

Esto lo que hace es que en pantallas inferiores a 600px se active esta opción.

Si pones por ejemplo:

```
@media (min-width: 800px) { ... }
```

Para las pantallas de 800 o mas pixeles se vera como lo que pongas en el lugar de los puntos suspensivos.

Tienes muchas combinaciones para conseguir el modelo que quieras.

Te recomiendo que pongas aquí, editando tu pregunta, el código de ese programa, para que podamos darte datos mas precisos.

Comment: lo ensayaré y te aviso, Gracias

Comment: el @media me ayudó bastante, aunque yo lo usé de la siguiente manera `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1350px) { ... }`, de todas formas muchas gracias